powershell parse xml escape equal sign
I have a xml file and I try to parse it in powershell with this cmd:
[xml]$userfile = Get-Content $userfilepath

It fails because one field of xml file which contains equal sign like below:
<photo>https://url/?include_plugin=downloader&file=/photos/33.jpg</photo>

for the photo field I need to extract url, and it happens that url contains equal (=) sign.
The error is:
Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "'=' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'. "
I generate the xml file in another system and I tried to change to by adding " ":
<photo>\"https://url/?include_plugin=downloader&file=/photos/33.jpg\"</photo>

I had same error.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

It's not the = that's the problem, it's that &... is an escape sequence in XML, so the parser sees &file= and goes "I don't recognize any escape sequence containing =".
Escape the & appropriately (as &amp;) and it'll work:
<photo>https://url/?include_plugin=downloader&amp;file=/photos/33.jpg</photo>

